# Is there an API or software that can provide historic traffic data?

Tags: api, maps, google-maps

I am looking for a API or software that can provide historical traffic data for a given location. I am open to something that doesn't quite meet my needs but the important thing is that it is historic data rather than live only data.

I have had a looking at the Google Maps and Bing API's but as far as I can tell they don't provide historic data. The Uber and TomTomAPIs seem to be quite promising but I don't think they cover many locations.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend taking a second look at the [TomTom APIs](https://developer.tomtom.com/). There should be extensive traffic history for most locations to cover your needs. [This question](https://developer.tomtom.com/routing-api-and-extended-routing-api/support/faq/do-routing-route-calculations-use-real-time-or-historic-traffic-information) should also partially address your concern, or at least prove that the info is available.